# Equal margin from Left and right UlLabel iOS

Tags: ios

I have a UILabel(I am using **AutoLayout**) in my chat screen and its showing me Sender's And Receiver's messages. Its expanding according to the text limit.**I am using this label in my custom cell in UItableview**. Prob is that when text limit is upto 1 line then its showing fine in a proper manner. But when the number of lines of text >1 means we have multiple Lines then the alignment is not working fine . The text starts from the very left end without any margin from left and right.  I want a proper alignment of text with fixed margin from top,left,right and bottom. I dont know how to achieve this. Can anybody demonstrate with an example(**Autolayout Enable**). I will be very thank full to them.

Comment: provide screen shot of your problem.

Comment: Sorrry I cant Dont Have reputation points for this

Comment: Sorry posting my answer very late.Just use: label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES; and CGRect rectt = [sstrAddress boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-20 , FLT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : stylee,NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]} context:nil];
            CGSize expectedLabelSizeee = rectt.size; pass this expectedLabelSizeee to height of the table